# SQL query - need help constructing

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, field

Just need some quick help constructing an sql query for a complete noob. I have copied the db schema below;

Comment: I don't think avail is something you would store

Comment: "However, DDate and TTime have to be taken into consideration when updating the value. "  -- what you mean?

Comment: Surely this should also be an update and not an insert as the `Chair` row should already exist when you change its availability. Oh and you UPDATE/INSERT a Table name i.e. `Chair`

Comment: i mean - I need to show the availability of a seat based on the date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design is off target.
The Avail attribute describes a general chair, not chair in a moment of time. Imagine you have two shows - one today, other in 10 days. People book today's show, the table Chair gets updated and the seat is now occupied. Now someone wants too book the later show and.. Doh, its occupied. And if you have 100 shows and each has only 1 attendee, you will still end up with 100 occupied chairs *for every show*.

This statement will give you all seats with their status for a particular show

```
select c.chair_id,
(case when b.chair_id is null then 1 else 0 end) available
from shows s
inner join booki1 b on s.show_id = b.show_id
left join chairs c on b.chair_id = c.chair_id
where s.show_id = *insert show id here*
```

This will select all available chairs for a particular show.
Also I would suggest using some auto incremented integer Id for chairs/shows.
And having two columns for date / time looks really strange when you can have a DateTime column. Takes some time to imagine a specific situation where you'd actually need that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - really helpful and can see where I have gone off target. From the schema, do you think it's possible to select all of the seats (regardless of whether they have been booked yet) but then indicate which ones have already been booked on my booking system? .. ideally, i want to fill my webpage with seats unavailable and available, and then style the unavailable ones as 'red' as an example

Comment: You can derive the available/unavailable when selecting, and it would make sense to create a View for this query. I will update my answer shortly

Comment: you can either make this into a View which would return info about all reservations for all shows by slightly modifying the query to include show_id for later filtering, or you can make it into a function and pass show_id as a parameter

Comment: thanks for your help - really appreciate it - will test it shortly!

Comment: Hi @evictednoise .. just tried the query and it doesn't return any chairno's back - it states it's an empty set. I have all the data in chairs and no data in Booki1 .. can you see a slight error in the code you provided?

Comment: @SamNeeds change the inner join to a left join.

Comment: @Shadow - just tried it - it now shows all fields in c.chair_id as 'null' and an available column with '1'. I need all of the chair_id's .. can you see what's happening? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SamNeeds if the bookings table is empty, then there is no booking at all, so all chairs should be available. This is your application, you should be aware which table means what.